# How to manage with the condition as per the sequence comes and store in json fomat

Tags: php, arrays, json

```
    $data = array(

        "category" => array (
           'content_category_ids'=>array(3983,3985,3987),               
            'condition' => 'AND'
        ),   

        "genre" => array (
         'genre_names'=>array('drama','fami'),
          'condition'=>'OR'
        ),     
        "cast" => array (
           'cast_ids' =>array(223,45,67),             
        )
     );
```

The above is my data comes and by this I want to make the combination like below :

```
{(("category":{"content_category_ids":[3983,3985,3987]}) AND ("genre":{"genre_names":["drama","fami"])) OR ("cast":{"cast_ids":[223,45,67])}
```

Simillary if I change the data like below :

```
        $data = array(      
        "genre" => array (
         'genre_names'=>array('drama','fami'),
          'condition'=>'OR'
        ),  
        "category" => array (
           'content_category_ids'=>array(3983,3985,3987),               
            'condition' => 'AND'
        ),   

        "cast" => array (
           'cast_ids' =>array(223,45,67),             
        )
     );
```

Then the combination comes like below :

```
{(("genre":{"genre_names":["drama","fami"]) OR ("category":{"content_category_ids":[3983,3985,3987])) AND ("cast":{"cast_ids":[223,45,67]})}
```

Comment: So it's possible to do with a loop over each item in $data and collecting true or false from previous for the comparison. But what is the actual check you're doing, "genre":{"genre_names":["drama","fami"]} isn't a comparison. I assume you're checking another variable's genre_names against these ones? Please update the question with more details on this.

Comment: Your desired output is not in the JSON format, yet you flagged the question with JSON. Can you elaborate on the format you want for the output?

Comment: Have I misunderstood the question, you want to store the data as that weird or and string? In that case this seems like an xy problem, I can't think of any reason anyone would want to do that.

Comment: "genre":{"genre_names":["drama","fami"] , is not comparision but we will manage with what is there in condition section. For example there are 3 data like Category, Genre and Cast and both category has subcategories.So while we want to retrieve the data we will check what is the condition present with them. I wnat to make combination like ((Category AND Genre) OR Cast) or ((Genre OR Category) AND Cast) . Like the way the condition present from left to right.

Comment: @PhilippMaurer, Yes we want output should be in json format.

Comment: @Shard, Like the combination we store we will retrieve the data as per the combination .

Comment: This isn't something you should be doing, use a supported format to represent your data instead. Also this isn't JSON as @PhilippMaurer told you.

Comment: Tangentially related: [Modify 2d array to create nested datasets when specific key is encountered](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75649132/2943403)